# How is it possible to communicate between two antenas supporting 20km and 5km distance at 5GHz frequency?

Tags: wireless

Is it possible to link two antennas supporting different distances 20km and 5km in full duplex mode?

If Antenna A such as Ubiquiti Rocket can support 20km distance using 5GHz frequency and Antenna B can support 5km distance at same 5GHz frequency. How the signal sent by Antenna B (5km) can reach Antenna A supporting 20km distance if they are placed 15km apart or is it possible at all?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:  No.

Wi-fi is a two way communication.  So station A can transmit a high power signal so B can hear it, but unless  A can hear B's signal, there is no two way communication.

Rating an antenna by distance is just a marketing technique. Antennas are normally rated by their "gain" (expressed in dB), or their ability to focus energy in a particular direction (like focussing a light). There are many factors that affect the usable distance: transmit (tx) power, tx antenna, path loss, receiver (rx) antenna, and rx sensitivity.  You need to take in all these factors to determine the usable distance.

The Ubiquiti Rocket is an access point, not an antenna.  It has antennas on it, and the gain of those antennas is regulated by the laws of the country where it's used.

Comment: Ubiquiti does indeed describe its antennas in dB and directionality, but also helpfully gives "serving suggestion" distances so you know if you're looking at the right product range.  Just to add to the things which affect usable distance: noise rejection, selectivity, reflection complexity, weather (rain) and season (vegetation) sensitivities.